# Move folder to BTRFS sub-volume

Tags: linux-mint, btrfs

I recently formatted my `/home` partition using BTRFS, but since it was my first touch with this FS, I didn't know about sub-volumes.

Yesterday I reinstalled my Linux Mint and selected to mount my existing home partition as `/home`. Now I was surprised, that my files first seemed to be lost, but then I noticed that Linux Mint created a sub-volume called `@home` next to my existing user home folder.

Current situation is the following disk layout: 
250 GiB SSD
-- 64 GiB / (BTRFS)
-- 8 GiB swap
-- ~170 GiB /home (BTRFS)

When I try to *move* my home folder into the `@home` sub-volume, I get the error that there isn't enough space left (?!) although there's ~50 GiB left on this partition and I want to move, and not to copy the files.
I haven't any other disk right now that I could reformat to any non-NTFS format, which would be required to keep any symlinks..

Now I got the question: How to move the files from the folder into the sub-volume correctly? And why doesn't moving the files work?

Comment: Can you please paste the logs of `mount` and `df -h` command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can attempt a COW (copy-on-write) copy with `cp -a --reflink=always /home/<whatever> /home/@home/`. It's a true copy as far as the Linux VFS (virtual filesystem) is concerned, but within BTRFS the files would share the same blocks/extends so no additional space is required until you modify the files.

If the copy succeeds, modify `/etc/fstab` to mount the subvolume instead of the whole filesystem:

```
/dev/sdXn    /home    btrfs    subvol=@home
```

Then, reboot. If all is well, you can remove the original files:

```
mount /dev/sdXn /mnt
pushd /mnt
rm -fR <whatever>
popd
umount /mnt
```

Of course, you should have backups before attempting any of this.

### Next

Once everything is good, *please* read the [BTRFS wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org), in particular all the articles under the *Guides and Usage Information*. BTRFS is pretty neat and all, but it doesn't work like your traditional Linux filesystems (extN, ReiserFS, etc.). It's not one of those things one can jump into and just figure out as you go. To use BTRFS well, you gotta know what you're doing. And reading the documentation is the best way to do that.

I happen to love BTRFS, and I hope you enjoy it as well.

Comment: Thanks! The --reflinks=always parameter did the magic :) Thought, that BTRFS automatically creates these references when using cp. Might it be ok to alias cp with "cp --reflinks=always"?

Comment: Check out this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80351/why-is-cp-reflink-auto-not-the-default-behaviour

Answer (score 5):

In case someone else also tries to use `mv` to move data between sub-volumes, which according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152639/81744 sounds like it should work / be fast (reflinks should be the default mode for `mv` since coreutils 8.24): My practical test with coreutils-8.29 on linux-4.14.15-arch shows that copies are being created instead of file system internal links (`df` shows the file system size increasing, which appears odd for `mv`, especially with reflinks).

Thus https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/377734/81744 continues to be the correct answer, even with newer versions of coreutils, which should default to reflinks for `mv`.

(I would have commented on the currently best answer to add this information, but I would need 50 reputation for that, which I don't yet have.)

Answer (score 1):

I was struck by the same issue. Splitting `/home` into parts for easier snapshot management turned into a weeks long nightmare. `cp --reflink=always` did not work for some reason (threw way too many errors at me I got lost in them).

The answer I've found at last was simple and so obvious, I'm ashamed I did not think of it before.

1. Snapshot the original subvolume.
2. Inside a snapshot, delete everything you don't need, and **move** the data you need to the root of the snapshot. Mostly it will be directories. It's fast and cheap.
3. Make sure ACL on the snapshot root is what you expect.
4. Mount your new subvolume where you want it.

If you've attempted to move across volumes before, but being a good system administrator, made a snapshot before that "just in case", there's a simple script to cleanup erroneous subvolume:

```
# cd /your/erroneous/subvolume
# find . -type f -exec cmp --silent '{}' '/your/good/snapshot/{}' \; -delete
```

This will remove from your erred subvolume any files that are same as those on your reserve snapshot. **Do not attempt to rsync "the rest" back into snapshot.** There could be partially copied files and you will lose data.
Manually inspect the residue and only copy what you actually need.

---

And here's the answer to `cp --reflink=always` and "Invalid cross-device link" errors: this doesn't mean FS is at fault, it's just how the kernel map from extent to filename work, if you specify *mounted* subvolumes as targets. Mount your *root FS,* go into that directory and work from there with relative paths. All will be good.

Comment: Yea, why didn't I think of this!  In my case I wanted to convert one subdirectory of an existing subvolume into a subvolume. I was already doing backup snapshots so did a snapshot of that as a subdirectory of the original (using a leading capital folder name to indicate a subvolume subdirectory and to not conflict with original).  Then I did #2 of your procedure.  When all was good I deleted the original (non subvolume) subdirectory.  Now I can take snapshots of just that subdirectory!  Beware, snapshots of parent subvolume won't include this subvolume subdirectory and must be done separately